# Coffee Roasters- 'Saving' a dictionary to a .txt file

Tags: python

Part of this homework problem I am working on is to save a file to an existing `.txt`-file which is `coffee.txt`. In the problem it says:

> To save the dictionary data to `coffee.txt`:
>
> - Create a new `temp.txt` file, in which you write every element in the dictionary.
> - Delete `coffee.txt`
> - Rename `temp.txt` to `coffee.txt`

Below is my save function: 
As stated my main problem is with saving (I can't use modules and I need to save the dictionary in the format like:
`key value` or `Sumatran 30`

```
tempfile = open('temp.txt', 'w')
for k, v in coffee_dict.items():
    dict_content = k + '' + v + '\n'
    tempfile.write(str(dict_content))
coffee = open('coffee.txt', 'w')
tempfile = coffee
print('Your file has been saved.')
```

Any ideas in what is going on? Also keep getting error:

> must be str, not int.

Comment: Please include the full error.  What is the data (keys and values) in the dictionary?

Comment: When asking a question for code that throws an exception, you should include the complete Traceback (formatted as code). Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Stack isn't meant for helping with homework but check the k and v are both strings. That seems most likely the reason ( using + only works with strings)

Comment: I can only guess without sufficient information but very likely `dict_content = k + '' + v + '\n'` is the error, if `v` is an integer and not a string. Instead `'%s%d\n' % (k, v)` or the appropriate `str.format` equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for you help the main problem was with the k and v values not being strings so I just changed them to str(k) and str(v) and it worked fine thanks